# Why does my Eclipse Luna 4.4 crash on Debian Wheezy 7.4 with Oracle JDK8 64bit?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, java-8

I have Debian GNU/Linux 7.4 (wheezy) OS installed on Oracle VirtualBox and:

> ```
> java version "1.8.0_11"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)
> ```

I downloaded Eclipse Luna 4.4.  When I was trying to run Eclipse an error occurred:

> ```
> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9e8a42173f, pid=10942, tid=140319582553856
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_11-b12) (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
> Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.11-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
> Problematic frame:
> C  [libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x5173f]  gdk_display_open+0x3f
> Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java
> ```

So I issued a command in the terminal:

```
$ ulimit -c unlimited
$ ./eclipse
```

But the next error occurred:

> ```
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support
> was removed in 8.0
> (java:11276): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `GdkDisplayManager'
> (java:11276): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed
> (java:11276): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
> (java:11276): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
> (java:11276): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
> (java:11276): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
> (java:11276): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
> (java:11276): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `GdkDisplay'
> (java:11276): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed
> (java:11276): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion `parent_type > 0' failed
> (java:11276): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed
> (java:11276): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f216d28473f, pid=11276, tid=139782222493440JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
> ```
>
> (8.0_11-b12) (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
>       Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.11-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>       Problematic frame:
>       C  [libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x5173f]  gdk_display_open+0x3f
>       Core dump written. Default location: /home/abcdef/ECLIPSE_JAVA/eclipse/core or core.11276

I also tried to solve this problem by adding:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

to eclipse.ini, but it didn't help.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: Try: `SWT_GTK3=0 ./eclipse`

Answer (score 80, accepted):

According to:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430736

Add to 2 lines eclipse.ini:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

The option --launcher.GTK_version should be *before* --launcher.appendVmargs

Problem (dialogs does not work properly) with TIBCO Jaspersoft® Studio - Visual Designer for JasperReports:

edit Jaspersoft Studio.ini like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.GTK_version
2
--launcher.library
```

Or add this before start Jasper Studio (**runubuntu.sh**):

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

Comment: --> Eclipse Mars the same solution.

Comment: Worked or me on  Kepler Service Release 2. The crash for me was happening during debug runs.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me (debian 7.8, eclipse luna, java8, openbox)

Answer (score 11):

I found this solution at [eclipse bugs page](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430736)

export SWT_GTK3=0

Answer (score 10):

try to edit your eclipse.ini file like this:

```
-startup
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.GTK_version
2
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: After seeing this I make it also point to java 7 and it worked

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Eclipse based Sping Tool Suite (STS) and JDK 8 when launching STS on Debian Wheezy 7.6 64-bit. Adding those two lines, as suggested by other answers, to the init file sts.ini (eclipse.ini) did the work.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.GTK_version
2
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
```

Answer (score 3):

Try launching Eclipse from command line with `-noSplash` option.
your error looked like this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=394227).

Answer (score 3):

"--launcher.GTK_version
2"

It's work for me also. Debian 7 + STS 4.4.1 , I have to add a line to eclipse.ini as ccer added.

Answer (score 3):

On Debian Wheezy 7.8 (64bit) & using `Eclipse` - `Luna 4.4.2`. Comments by **`harshrc`** on [Bug 430736](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430736) were the most relevant in my case and resolved crash post splash screen. Launch eclipse with *`export SWT_GTK3=0`*

```
# from CLI / prompt in eclipse folder:
export SWT_GTK3=0 ; ./eclipse
```

Comment: This also works with Debian Jessie and Eclipse Neon.

Comment: You are entirely retaking the answer of harshrc. It would have been fairer to do just a comment instead.

Answer (score 1):

After [installing JDK 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps) from Oracle, I modified eclipse.ini and made it point to Java 7 from Oracle. I then read the posting form [arash javan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2335224/arash-javan) and I modified eclipse.ini to point to the correct version of GTK.  After these two mods, eclipse works in Debian 7.  If you want to use JDK 8, I am sure this will still work.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.GTK_version
2
-vm
/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```