# Eclipse Luna 4.4 repeated crashes on Linux Mint 17 with Oracle JDK 7

Tags: eclipse, java-7, eclipse-luna, linux-mint

Full details recorded [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=462392):

But in essence, while editing plain Java code, IDE will randomly crash after 4 or 5 lines have been typed leaving no trace as to what exactly happened.  I have recently installed GNU/Linux Mint 17.1 64-bit and so far everything else has worked fine.  Eclipse Luna 64-bit is the only app that is misbehaving.

This problem is not the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872995/why-does-my-eclipse-luna-4-4-crash-on-debian-wheezy-7-4-with-oracle-jdk8-64bit) but just for kicks I tried the fix suggested.  Needless to say that it did not work.

I have searched around but I seem to be the only one with this problem.  Can anyone at least suggest how I can start to debug this?

Comment: Problem disappears if you install from **eclipse-SDK-4.5M5a-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz**

Comment: Corrected comment and removed non-solution