# Eclipse freezes when creating project/class (no loading bar showing)

Tags: java, eclipse

When creating new project (Java) in Eclipse Mars.2 version, there's a problem, that appears as like "freezing" of Eclipse: after clicking finish, CPU usage jumps high, it shows that it is building the project but everything is still - there's not even a loading bar underneath.

It appears the same when creating Java classes. The same happens when I start program from terminal - with and without "sudo". While loading everything, I seem to see no errors.

What could be wrong? Dunno with what I should even start, but tell me, what specific info I should provide to investigate this.
I have tried changing GTK theme to something else, reinstalled Eclipse n-th times (did that by unarchiving and using installer provided from eclipse.org), reinstalled Java from ground-up, still nothing changes.

Dealing with this over 2 months, still can't find any solution. Many things I have tried, even researched related topics before posting this. Nothing helped from there.

Using now Ubuntu 16.04 (unstable, but it shouldn't be a problem, I guess).

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Comment: Different symptoms, but same answers, so might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24872995/1639625

Answer (score 4):

You can create file `run.sh` in eclipse directory and add this content

```
#!/bin/bash

export SWT_GTK3=0
./eclipse
```

now run eclipse using `./run.sh` instead of official `./eclipse` launcher.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the GTK version. 
Just add this line to the eclipse.ini file just before

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
```

line -

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

Comment: Remove the image. You cannot use copy/paste with it and it may vanish one day. Instead describe which file to edit and what to edit.

Comment: Still, the image does not add anything useful to the answer, better just post the content of the config file, or just the added parts, as code.