# The Perspective toolbar disappears in KDE

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-14.04, toolbar, kde-plasma, eclipse-neon

I have an issue with the Perspective toolbar in Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) running in Ubuntu 14.04.5:

- The toolbar is visible when I run Eclipse in Gnome
- The toolbar is not visible when I run Eclipse in KDE

In KDE, when I click Windows -> New window, the Perspective toolbar appears. But when I close all windows and start Eclipse again, the Perspective toolbar is not visible again.

I tried to remove `~/.eclipse` and `$WORKSPACE/.metadata`. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17610676/1800052) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21707508/1800052), but that did not help.

What might be the reason and how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.0) with KDE on RHEL 7.2 (remotely accessed with PCoIP Agent/Client) and have also encountered this problem of the missing Perspective toolbar, along with other issues:

- Unsightly rectangular boxes around menu items.
- Unreadable dark-grey-on-black text in Editors dialog.
- Eclipse crashing when I open Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective.

While exploring solutions for an unrelated display issue, I came across a suggestion to [force Eclipse to use GTK2](https://coffeeorientedprogramming.com/2014/10/27/how-to-tell-if-you-are-running-eclipse-on-gtk2-or-on-gtk3/) by defining `SWT_GTK3=0` in the environment before starting eclipse (this example is for Bash):

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
eclipse
```

When I did this, not only did the Perspectives toolbar appear, it also solved all the other problems mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, this has worked! [Another option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25153671/1800052) is to add `--launcher.GTK_version\n2` before `--launcher.appendVmargs` in `eclipse.ini`.